# I have a function for plotting the map (python) . How can I plot the function output in different subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

[Link to original function code](https://websites.pmc.ucsc.edu/~joeyajames/scripts/mapmaker3.py)

I have modified this function given in the link as per my needs. But I am not able to assign the outputs from the function to different subplots. Is there any way to do it?

```
    x1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
    plot_map(data1, lat, lon)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
    plot_map(data2, lat, lon)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(223)
    plot_map(data3, lat, lon)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(224)
    plot_map(data4, lat, lon)
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example with all required code in the question! Links tend to break.

Answer (score 0):

yes, just pass the Axes object (`ax2`) into the function and set it as the current Axes:

Add a variable for the Axes object to the function signature:

```
def plot_map(data, lat, lon, ax):
```

And replace the line `fig=plt.figure()` with `plt.sca(ax)`. Then call the function like: `plot_map(data2, lat, lon, ax2)`.